# Firebase Database loop through children starting from last child

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have this loop through children:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                przejazd = postSnapshot.getValue(Przejazd.class);
                System.out.println(przejazd.getAdres_koniec());
                przejazdList.add(przejazd);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
```

But I want to loop from last child to first child, how to do it?

Comment: Why do not you reverse przejazdlist?
This would give you the sa,e effect of looping from last to first child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, you can't do it with current API.
If you want to `reverse` it, you can do it with the obtained list.

```
Collections.reverse(przejazdList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't order your data in descending order in Firebase. Refer this [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156996/firebase-data-desc-sorting-in-android)
and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303830/how-to-retrieve-data-from-firebase-database-in-descending-order)

More convinient way would be reverse your list by

`Collections.reverse(yourList);`