# Android Firebase retrieve first 2 values of each child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Android, I like to retrieve only the last(descending) 2 key-value of each child.

[image]

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

    mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I know you can't reverse the order of the dataSnapshot.getChildren() as mentioned in [Firebase Database loop through children starting from last child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879905/firebase-database-loop-through-children-starting-from-last-child/45880061#45880061)

But for your particular problem what you can do

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

    List<DataSnapshot> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (DataSnapshot dsp: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        list.add(snapshot);
    }

    // It reverses the order of the list.
    Collections.reverse(list);

    // Now list.get(0) and list.get(1) are the snapshots you need!
}
```