# Retrieve from Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a Firebase DB and I'm using the Push() method to save data into the DB. This works fine. But this issue I'm facing is when I retrieve the data. As Push() works by creating a temporary key, I don't know how to step into the child of that tree to perform sorting using orderByValue(). My JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "videos" : {
    "videoId1" : {
      "-KhxlA5-yIHYq-7PQC84" : "{\"url\":\"testUrl1\",\"title\":\"test1\",\"x\":-3.9357306957244875,\"y\":6.528204441070557,\"z\":2.5558924674987795,\"time\":7982.197021484375}",
      "-KhxlAEpJp30xF5n6kc5" : "{\"url\":\"testUrl2\",\"title\":\"test2\",\"x\":4.0330400466918949,\"y\":6.52820348739624,\"z\":2.3994064331054689,\"time\":2637.8599853515625}",
      "-KhxlAPyaGEI7AxFssG_" : "{\"url\":\"testUrl3\",\"title\":\"test3\",\"x\":-3.446043014526367,\"y\":6.52820348739624,\"z\":-3.1854910850524904,\"time\":5350.770263671875}"
    }
  }
}
```

My requirement is that I need to sort it based on the `time` key while retrieving the data.

I can reach until the `videoId1` tree but don't know how to get past that. (Using `reference.Child ("videos").Child (videoUrl)`)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `var ref = reference.child('videos/videoId1').orderByChild('time')`?

Answer (score 1):

You're storing a string value for each child under `videoId1`. There is no way to usefully query inside that string.

If you want to query under those children, make sure to store the data as JSON, so that the total tree becomes:

```
{
  "videos": {
    "videoId1": {
        "-KhxlA5-yIHYq-7PQC84": {
            "url": "testUrl1",
            "title": "test1",
            "x": -3.9357306957244875,
            "y": 6.528204441070557,
            "z": 2.5558924674987795,
            "time": 7982.197021484375
        }
        ",
        "-KhxlAEpJp30xF5n6kc5": {
            "url": "testUrl2",
            "title": "test2",
            "x": 4.0330400466918949,
            "y": 6.52820348739624,
            "z": 2.3994064331054689,
            "time": 2637.8599853515625
        }
        ",
        "-KhxlAPyaGEI7AxFssG_": {
            "url": "testUrl3",
            "title": "test3",
            "x": -3.446043014526367,
            "y": 6.52820348739624,
            "z": -3.1854910850524904,
            "time": 5350.770263671875
        }
    }
  }
}
```

With that you can query as Kirill suggested:

```
ref.child('videos/videoId1').orderByChild('time')...
```